# Azure Conditional Access - Want to block sign in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, conditional-statements

I got around 20 users need to limit their sign in to only one device for office365 services including outlook. In case they attempt to login from second device, admin should receive notification to decide approve or reject device registration.
I understand this is possible but I have no idea, how this has to be designed.

Answer (score 0):

**To achieve your scenario, you can make use of conditional policies**

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:

Initially, create an **Azure AD group** by including those 20 users.

Next, I created one conditional policy by selecting below values:
In users, select the above group:

[image]

Under cloud apps, select **office365** like below:

[image]

Under conditions, select filter for devices and include the device ID:

[image]

Based on requirement, select the **condition** accordingly:

[image]

**Now, create the conditional policy by enabling policy to ON:**

[image]